# What does "~." mean in R?

Tags: r, model, tilde, model.matrix

it's the first time I've used the model.matrix command on R. I'm posting the code from an example found in a book:

```
model.matrix(~., data)
```

I don't understand what `~.` is.

Looking on the internet I saw that the first argument would be "an object of an appropriate class" but I don't understand what `~.` is.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `formula` data type in R that specifies some selection and transformation of columns in a dataframe as input to a modeling or mathematical function.

For example,

`lm(mpg ~ wt + hp, data = mtcars)`

Will fit a linear model with `mpg` as the response (y) variable and `wt` and `hp` as the predictor (x) variable, both taken from the mtcars dataframe.

Why is this useful?  Well, without it, you have to prepare `x` and `y` matrix arguments every time you fit a model.  This is how most other mathematical languages work and it's kind of a pain.  You'd have to write something like

```
# pseudo-code
x <- as.matrix(mtcars[, c("wt", "hp")])
y <- mtcars[, "mpg"]
fit_lm(x, y)
```

The formula type makes it easy and agile to try models with various terms or transformations (i.e. `log(mpg) ~ wt + hp`) without having to define `x` and `y` inputs every...single...time.

The formula type also avoids having to type a lot of indexing `$` or `[]` or quotes `"hp"`.  Elegance is prized in R and it's nice to have clean code without lots of quotes and brackets.

The `~` symbol is a part of a formula.  It separates the response and predictor variables in specification of a model.  Or, sometimes, there is a one-sided formula if the math has now equivalent of a response variable and it's just `~x1 + x2`.

The `.` is a shorthand for "include all other columns."  So, `mpg ~ .` is shorthand for `mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + vs + am + gear + carb`.

`model.matrix` is a function that creates the matrix input to a regression.  It will expand out `factor` variables into dummy variables.  It will keep numeric variables as-is.  If there is a transformation defined in the formula, it will perform it.  You can give it the set of variables to the right of the `~` and it will do all this preparation for you.

Answer (score 0):

The dot means all columns in your data.frame not otherwise mentioned.

Running a few examples with the iris dataset shows this pretty well.

```
library(tidyverse)

model.matrix( ~ ., data = iris) %>% colnames()
# [1] "(Intercept)"       "Sepal.Length"      "Sepal.Width"      
# [4] "Petal.Length"      "Petal.Width"       "Speciesversicolor"
# [7] "Speciesvirginica" 

model.matrix( ~ Petal.Length, data = iris) %>% colnames()
# [1] "(Intercept)"  "Petal.Length"

model.matrix(Petal.Length ~ ., data = iris) %>% colnames()
# [1] "(Intercept)"       "Sepal.Length"      "Sepal.Width"      
# [4] "Petal.Width"       "Speciesversicolor" "Speciesvirginica"
```

You could forgo the `.` syntax and spell it out. I think this is a better approach since in this case a reader does not need to know what the columns in `iris` are. You can just tell what our model will include. It also has the side effect of preventing you from including something accidentally.

```
model.matrix( ~ Petal.Length + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris) %>% colnames()
# [1] "(Intercept)"       "Sepal.Length"      "Sepal.Width"      
# [4] "Petal.Length"      "Petal.Width"       "Speciesversicolor"
# [7] "Speciesvirginica"
```

Another resource on making these model matrices that I have used is this article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7873980/. It's specific for RNA seq, but the model matrices can be used for any similar style of comparison/model.